# add new extension attribute to the response of quote item (/V1/carts/:cartId)

Tags: magento2, soap, web-services, service-contract

I am trying to add some custom extension_extributes (For example: is_free_product & unit_price) to item node response of `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository::get($cartId)`

Here is what I tried so far

**1. Added extension_attributes**
File `app/code/MagePsycho/WebService/etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
        <attribute code="is_free_product" type="int" />
        <attribute code="unit_price" type="float" />
    </extension_attributes>
```

**2. Added plugin configuration**
File `app/code/MagePsycho/WebService/etc/di.xml`

```
...
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository">
        <plugin name="CtvPluginQuoteRepository" type="Ctv\WebService\Plugin\Webapi\QuoteRepository"/>
    </type>
...
```

**3. Added plugin class**
File `app/code/MagePsycho/WebService/Plugin/QuoteRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace MagePsycho\WebService\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_WebService
 * @author     Raj KB <magepsycho@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class QuoteRepository
{
    /**
     * Update quote with custom fields
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param int $cartId
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $proceed($cartId);

        if ($quote && $quoteItems = $quote->getItems()) {
            $baseToQuoteRate = $quote->getBaseToQuoteRate();
            $quoteItemObjects = [];
            foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
                $extensionAttributes = $quoteItem->getExtensionAttributes();

                if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
                    $extensionAttributes = $this->getQuoteItemExtensionDependency();
                }

                // is_free_product
                $isFreeProduct = (int) $quoteItem->getIsFreeProduct();
                $extensionAttributes->setIsFreeProduct($isFreeProduct);

                // unit_price
                $unitPrice  = (float) number_format($baseToQuoteRate * $quoteItem->getPrice(), 4, '.', '');
                $extensionAttributes->setUnitPrice($unitPrice);

                $quoteItem->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
                $quoteItemObjects[] = $quoteItem;
            }
            $quote->setItems($quoteItemObjects);
        }

        return $quote;
    }

    private function getQuoteItemExtensionDependency()
    {
        $quoteItemExtension = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            '\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtension'
        );
        return $quoteItemExtension;
    }
}
```

But in the response, Always get as 0 value for both unitPrice & isFreeProduct.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: hi please confirm whether you got the solution for this question?